# Stuck in Verify your account

Tags: factory-reset, 7.0-nougat, safe-mode, frp

Stuck in Verify your account, I have only Google Voice keyboard and I cant type my number or `@`, what to do?

I can't  do anything with factory reset, i can't get in safe mode.

Comment: Why don't you install a keyboard app ?

Comment: Please don't abuse the post by deleting it. You asked a question and it has useful answers that may help someone

Answer (score 2):

In the corners on the bottom of keyboard there are icons. Example: (?!)
click that, it will give you @ and other characters you need.